# Embed code in video file

Tags: php, video

I'm sorry if the question is ambiguous, I'll try to explain.

I'm working on an existing PHP download script for videos and some parts of it are broken. There's code in there that's supposed to place a specific member code inside the video file before download, but it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
//embed user's code in video file
$fpTarget = fopen($filename, "a");
fwrite($fpTarget, $member_code);
fclose($fpTarget);
```

$member_code is a random 6-character code.

Now, this would make sense to me if it were a text file, but since it's a video file, how could this possibly work and what is it supposed to do? If the member code is somehow added to the video, how can I see it after download it? I have no experience with video files, so any help is appreciated (a modification of the available code or new code would be equally welcome).

I'm sorry I can't give a more precise description of what the code is supposed to do, I'm trying to figure that out myself.

Comment: What video format(s) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may work, depending on the format/type of the video. MPG files are fairly tolerant of "noise" in a file and players would skip over your code because it doesn't look like valid video frame data.

Other formats/players may puke, because the format requires certain data be at specific offsets relative to the end of the file, which you've now shifted by 6 characters.

Your best bet is to figure see if whatever format you're serving up has provisions for metadata in its specifications. e.g. there might be support for a comment field somewhere that you can simply slap the code into.

However, if you're doing all this for 'security' or tracking unauthorized sharing of the video, then simply writing the number into a header is fairly easy to bypass. A better bet would be to watermark the video somehow so that the code is embedded in the actual video data, so that "This video belongs to member XYZ only" is displayed while playing.

Comment: Thank you. The website is thinking of watermarking them anyway, this is a temporary solution. The format is mostly mp4. Do you know how tolerant that is?

Comment: mp4 does have provisions for metadata. you'd have to dig up the official specifications though, though there are tools that you manipulate it from the command line (and probably gui versions): http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/285993-MP4-Metadata-tags-How-to-add

Answer (score 0):

You don't write to the content of the file directly, not like you would with a text file.  As you've noticed, this effectively corrupts the video and you have no way of reasonably reading the information.

For audio/video files, you write to meta-data that's packaged with the file.  How this is packaged and what you can do with it generally depends heavily on the container format used for the file.  (Remember that container and codec are two different things.  The codec is the format used to encode the audio/video, the container is the file format in which that data stream is stored.)

A library like [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) might be a good place to start.  I've never used it, but it seems to be what you're looking for.  What you would essentially do is write a value to the meta-data in the container (either a pre-defined value for that container or maybe a custom key/value pair, etc.) which would be part of the file.  Then, when reading the file, you can get that data.  (Now, that last part depends heavily on what's reading the file.  The data is there, but not every player cares about it.  You'll want to match up what you're writing to with what you usually see/read from the file's internal meta-data.)